# Why don't my images load in Vue.js 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to get my images to load via a relative path in Vue.js 2 but something seems off. I'm just getting my feet wet with regard to Vue and would appreciate any pointers. Said images are in the /src/assets/imgs directory.

Below are the relevant code snippets for the component in question.

[image: File tree screenshot]

```
<template>
  <section class="container sources">
        <h2>{{ heading }}</h2> 
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column" v-for="source in sources">
                <figure :title="source">
                    <img :src="imgPath + source + '.png'" :alt="source + ' logo'">
                    <figcaption>{{ source }}</figcaption>        
                </figure>        
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   name: 'sources',
   data () {
      return {
          heading: 'News Sources',
          imgPath: 'src/assets/imgs/',
          sources: [
            'al-jazeera-english', 'associated-press', 'bbc-news', 'bbc-sport', 'business-insider', 'cnn', 
            'daily-mail', 'entertainment-weekly', 'espn', 'financial-times', 'fox-sports', 'hackernews', 
            'ign','independent', 'mtv-news', 'national-geographic', 'new-scientist', 'reuters', 'techcrunch', 'the-economist', 'the-guardian-uk', 'the-huffington-post', 'the-new-york-times', 
                'the-washington-post'
           ]
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

**Edit:** Added a screenshot of my project's (simple) file tree upon request. Said images are in the 'imgs' folder, of course.

Comment: Check what `src` is being assigned to the images, your code works fine, probably the path needs some tweaking. https://jsfiddle.net/s379dL6s/

Comment: @yuriy636 I get the 'correct' paths, as in what is expected if they were referenced in a simple .html file, but the images just won't load. I have no clue as to why they don't.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your file tree?

Comment: @aprouja1 I've included a simple screenshot of my project's file tree.

Comment: If you're using the webpack template from `vue-cli` (which it looks like you are), then read this ~ https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html

Comment: You could also be running in to this bug ~ https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/814

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you're using the webpack template from `vue-cli`, you can simply use a relative path for [static assets](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html).

```
<img :src="'./assets/imgs/' + source + '.png'"
```

---

Alternatively, put your images in the `static` directory and reference them with an absolute path, ie

```
<img :src="'/static/imgs/' + source + '.png'"
```

Comment: Hello. I actually went to the page you suggested before posting this question. Nothing they suggested worked. I also tried a similar approach to what you're suggesting but no bueno.

Comment: @CollinsOrlando Check your browser's *Network* console. Look for the image file requests. What do they look like?

Comment: Status: 404 as expected. Here is the link to the screenshot. http://imgur.com/AAbVpHN.png. Ignore the puppy images. Those are of a random Google image link.

Comment: @CollinsOrlando maybe the expression isn't handling the template literal. Try `:src="'./assets/imgs/' + source + '.png'"`

Comment: I greatly appreciate the suggestions. Unfortunately, I've already tried (most of) them, but to no avail. I'll look into the link you posted, above.

Comment: @CollinsOrlando good luck. Seems using the `static` directory works for most folks with this same problem

Comment: Using the static folder surprisingly solved the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

This should work

```
<img :src="image" >
data () {
  return {
    image: require('@/assets/images/pin.svg')
  }
},
```

Comment: Why should this work? Please edit your question to include an explanation to help future readers

Comment: Muuuuuito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente para mim.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used **../assets/{name of image}** :

src/components/SomeComponent.vue

```
<style>
    .black.square{
        background: url(../assets/logo.png);
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a link to list contained in an assets folder via JS in Vue.js you must first import the image:

import img from '@/assets/myImage.png'

Then refer to the imported image file in a variable:
image:img,

Then lastly src the img to the img tag:
:src="image"