# How do you include an assets folder in a Vue file?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, assets, photoeditorsdk

I tried this (I'm using Vue's official [Webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack)):

```
data () {
  photoEditorAssets: require('../assets/img/photoeditorsdk/assets'),
}

mounted () {
   var editor = new PhotoEditorSDK.UI.DesktopUI({ //eslint-disable-line
      container: container,
      assets: {
        baseUrl: this.photoEditorAssets // <-- This should be the absolute path to your `assets` directory
      }
    })
  }
}
```

However, I get this error:

> Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'E:\alex\vreditor\src\assets\img\photoeditorsdk\assets'

Maybe the code is searching for a file called assets?

How to properly import a folder in a Vue file?

Note: Here's the structure of my project:

[image]

Comment: I'd just use the `static` folder. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44959724/283366

Comment: @PhI get the same error: `Can't resolve '/static/photoeditorsdk/assets/'`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W9dK.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how `require()` works. What you want is only the absolute path.

Simply something like this should work for you.

```
data () {
  photoEditorAssets: '../assets/img/photoeditorsdk/assets',
}
```

Comment: I tried that but `photoEditorAssets` only becomes a string: `'../assets/img/photoeditorsdk/assets/'`

Comment: @alex Exactly. It should be a string. A string that specify the path.

Comment: The url becomes like this: `http://localhost:8080/buildings/44fcb985-2e0c-44f6-9014-c053c2369908/assets/ui/desktop/editor/controls/focus/icon.png 404 (Not Found)` It injects itself in the current URL.

Comment: This worked:   `baseUrl: '/static/photoeditorsdk/assets' /`