# Images are not showing (VueJS -- using v-for)

Tags: vuejs2, src, v-for

So I'm pretty new to VueJS and I've been using it to create a gridlike image gallery. I tried to use v-for to display the images by looping through a JSON file with information about each image. I'll include all that. But this is what shows up (screenshot):
[so the images don't show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtFyi.png)

I've nonuple-checked the links in relation to the file structure. So here's the code of the component that contains the gallery of images (mind you, the href links DO work):

```
<template>
<div>
  <div v-for="data in images" v-bind:key="data">
    <h2>{{data.Name}}</h2>
    <a :href="'#'+data.Name">
      <img :src="'../../../img/products/'+data.Name+'.png'" :alt="data.Name+'.png'" />
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
</template>

<script>
  import Prods from '../../../other/jsons/products.json'
  export default {
    data() {
      return {images: Prods}
    }...</script>
```

Here's the JSON file (it does fetch the data btw, evidently):

```
[
  {
    "ImageId": 0,
    "Name": "drinks"
  },
  {
    "ImageId": 1,
    "Name": "preppedfood"
  },
  {
    "ImageId": 2,
    "Name": "coffee"
  },
  {
    "ImageId": 3,
    "Name": "snacks"
  },
  {
    "ImageId": 4,
    "Name": "nuts"
  },
  {
    "ImageId": 5,
    "Name": "bars"
  },
  {
    "ImageId": 6,
    "Name": "water"
  },
  {
    "ImageId": 7,
    "Name": "fruit"
  },
  {
    "ImageId": 8,
    "Name": "cookies"
  },
  {
    "ImageId": 9,
    "Name": "cereal"
  },
  {
    "ImageId": 10,
    "Name": "healthfood"
  },
  {
    "ImageId": 11,
    "Name": "healthdrinks"
  },
  {
    "ImageId": 12,
    "Name": "waterdispenser"
  },
  {
    "ImageId": 13,
    "Name": "cutlery"
  },
  {
    "ImageId": 14,
    "Name": "office"
  },
  {
    "ImageId": 15,
    "Name": "more"
  }
]
```

Here's my file structure: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F0n3.png)

Comment: Your urls should be relative the the build destination, and to avoid all problems you should probably use webpack's [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader)

Comment: check this [Why don't my images load in Vue.js 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959724/why-dont-my-images-load-in-vue-js-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your img folder into /static folder and modify your path
see :
[image: webpack.dev.conf.js]